# how to use count function with a textbox in mysql to show search results in c# visual studio

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

[enter image description here][1]

In my code I am using a datagridview to show the NIC Number to the customer. Then if we press the Calculate button, other text boxes must fill with relevent details. its all done. But the count is still remained. i cannot use count command, Shows an error in mysql syntax.

i want to count the items according to the NIC number. The help is highly appreciated.

```
private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                textBox11.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            }
        }


private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (textBox11.Text == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select an Item");
            }
            else
            {
                con.Open();
                string SelectQuery = "select * from cheque where national_id =" + (textBox11.Text);
                MySqlCommand cmdDDDD = new MySqlCommand(SelectQuery, con);
                mdr2 = cmdDDDD.ExecuteReader();

                if (mdr2.Read())
                {
                    textBox2.Text = mdr2.GetString("customer_name");

                    con.Close();
                    mdr2.Close();
                    Countmmm();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No cheque from this ID");
                    con.Close();
                    mdr2.Close();
                }
            }
        }

public void Countmmm()
        {

            con.Open();
            string MysqlStringnow = "SELECT count(national_id) from cheque ='" + textBox11.Text + "'";
            MySqlCommand mycqlcommandNow = new MySqlCommand(MysqlStringnow, con);
            Int32 Rows_count = Convert.ToInt32(mycqlcommandNow.ExecuteScalar());
            mycqlcommandNow.Dispose();
            textBox4.Text = Rows_count.ToString();
            con.Close();

        }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS6D2.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a sintax error in the sql query, you forgot the 'where national_id' , and it´s incomplete, you should do it this way:

```
public void Countmmm()

    {

        con.Open();
        string MysqlStringnow = "SELECT count(national_id) from cheque where national_id='" + textBox11.Text + "'";
        MySqlCommand mycqlcommandNow = new MySqlCommand(MysqlStringnow, con);
        Int32 Rows_count = Convert.ToInt32(mycqlcommandNow.ExecuteScalar());
        mycqlcommandNow.Dispose();
        textBox4.Text = Rows_count.ToString();
        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Ahh. I got it. Stupid me. Thanks Sir